# Quartz.Net GetNextValidTimeAfter() throws exception for DST

Tags: quartz.net

Currently I am using Quartz.Net Scheduler to schedule different jobs. In the UI User can configure the Frequency i.e. Weekly and Day of Week and Time, to trigger the Job. Once the User can configure these proprieties I am currently displaying the Next Trigger Time.

Example: Every Week On Sunday 2 AM
CronString: 0 0 2 ? * SUN *
Current Date: 8th Mar 2013 Friday
Timezone : EST UTC-5.30 
Next Trigger Time: 10th Mar 2013 Sunday 2:00 AM

This one is working fine. But if DST will start on 10th Feb then there would not be 2:00 AM on that day. So the CronExpression throws following error:

```
CronExpression exp = new CronExpression(cronStr);
var dt = exp.GetNextValidTimeAfter(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()).Value.ToLocalTime();
return String.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", dt);
```

Exception: ArgumentException thrown. 
Message: "The supplied DateTime represents an invalid time."

As there is no such datetime exist in Calendar, I want to skip that day and will show the next valid date i.e.  17th Mar 2013 Sunday 2:00 A.M

Help me how can I fix this as it is internally thrown by .Net CLR in Quartz code.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223631/ways-to-deal-with-daylight-savings-time-with-quartz-cron-trigger/23819952#23819952

Answer (score 1):

You can use TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsInvalidTime to see if the time is valid, this will return true for times between 2:00 am to 3:00 am on 2nd Sunday of march (DST begin day for most of the United States and Canada).

more information is provided here
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/06/11/system-timezoneinfo-working-with-ambiguous-and-invalid-points-in-time-josh-free.aspx