# Quartz does not run the jobs, when the winter time change occurs

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

In our system, there are multiple quartz (quartz 2.2.2) schedules and jobs, which are associated to these schedules.

The problem appears when the winter time change (DST) occurs. Winter time change sets the hours back to the 02:00 am at 03:00 am (Berlin).

That means there are 2 times 02:00 am hours at that night. However, quartz api does not support DST. It skips both 2 am and continues when it is 03:00 am. In their [documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/faq.html#FAQ-daylightSavings), they say, *deal with it.*

01:00 am - works correctly
02:00 am - skips
02:00 am - works correctly
03:00 am - works correctly

In our system, we do not have a chance to set the timer on another time and the jobs must be triggered.

I have read almost all the answers on internet and did not find a suitable solution to this problem. The most logical answer (ron's answer) is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223631/ways-to-deal-with-daylight-savings-time-with-quartz-cron-trigger) however, I cannot extend CronExpression class, which is final. Possibly, it was not final in the previous versions.

Elegant or not, I am waiting for (and appreciate) all possible answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem with my own *hybrid* solution.

Mainly, in the class, which the jobs are done (the ones, which implement Job interface), I have always checked when the job will be triggered next time. If it is in the last sunday of the october at 02:00 am (The winter change occurs in the last sunday of the october), I reschedule the job with a simple trigger (which is not affected by Daylight saving time changes), and serialized the original trigger and after 03:00 am, I reschedule the job again with the original cron trigger.

I know this is not the ideal solution but I think it is the one of the best solution to this problem.